# Reducing tree of attributes

Tags: java, recursion, tree, min

I have a tree of several thousand nodes, decorated by boolean attributes, something like this (attributes in parentheses):

```
Root (x=true, y=true, z=false)
   Interior 1
       Leaf 1 (x=false, z=false)
       Leaf 2 (x=false, y=false, z=false)
   Interior 2
       Leaf 3
   etc.
```

What I would like to do is find the smallest number of decorations necessary to preserve the values of the attributes, given the following constraints/info:

1. Attributes are inherited by child nodes
2. Only the resulting attributes of the leaf nodes are important (including inherited attributes). So if setting a "default" attribute on an interior node lets me drop a bunch of attributes on its children, that's okay.
3. There is a shorthand in our model for setting all attributes to either true or false. For example, `(x=false,y=false,z=false)` can be represented by one decorator, whereas `(x=false,y=false,z=true)` would take three.
4. The number of child nodes will greatly outnumber the interior nodes (at least 25 to 1)
5. The initial state of the tree will have many redundancies.
6. I'm using Java and adding an external lib to deal with this isn't a big deal.

These constraints are not flexible as I'm working on an integration layer with a Large Enterprise System, so all I can do is try to minimize the number of attribute values we have to store and transit.

I think constraint #3 is throwing me for a loop, because without it I could just deal with each attribute individually, which is simple (and I already implemented a solution to that before I realized more attributes were coming).

I hope this is descriptive enough to give a picture of the general problem. I can give more examples or information if required. Thank you!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You don't need the absolutely *smallest* number, do you?

Comment: @MelNicholson: The question is what algorithm will result in the smallest number of decorations. My hope was that it was reducible to a well-known problem that I haven't seen or that this is actually really easy and I'm just dense :)

Comment: @JohnTangBoyland: No, it's definitely a want and not a need. I have a solution that gets me maybe halfway there already (solving for each attribute separately) but I noticed that I could probably throw away even more decorations by taking advantage of constraint #3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (3.) can be mainly ignored because we'd only be interested in it for leaves.
Here's what I would suggest:

1. for every leaf with all booleans one way, use the shortcut (3.).
2. Then for every internal node, assign attributes to the majority value for leaves below, not handled by 1, and remove the now redundant assignments.
3. For higher internal nodes, do the same, looking at immediate children, up to the root.

This is a heuristic, and I haven't tried it, but would be my first shot if I were you.
Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hmm, I like the idea of going with the majority. It isn't necessarily optimal, but it would be fast, which is a bonus. I'll try it out next chance I get, thanks.

Comment: Each of the steps above should have a caveat that if the value you would set matches what you would inherit, inherit instead.  This can be provisionally saving all the attributes as you build the tree, then discarding any that match the parent.

Comment: @MelNicholson, At the risk of getting into "chat", I don't think the caveat that you suggest applies since the heuristic that I describe is a bottom-up one.  The "remove the now redundant assignments" step has the effect you are looking for.

Comment: We ended up going with an approach similar to this one, thanks for the help.